# can I change my mind after signing contract?

Tags: job-offer, ethics, resignation

When I was waiting a feedback from company A I have received a job offer from company B. After that I informed company A that I have received official job offer from another company. Company A said that they need one more day to hear from their clients and tell me a decision. Then I asked company B for few days time to think. But they said that they cannot wait and and take risks and next day they invited me to their office to sign a contract. So I haven't had a choice and had to decide quickly. I was thinking that better have a "bird in hands", because I still didn't know decision of company A at that time.

So I went to company B office, signed a contract and agreed to work for them. But that day evening company A offered me a job. After that I informed company B that company A want me to work for them. Representative of company B replied that they put on first place my conscience and that I must keep a promised word. He also said that I will damage their company if I change my mind, and that they already arranged everything. I was little bit afraid and was feeling like I am on the pressure all the time. So I agreed again and promised to work for them.

The offer of company B is pretty good, but I have a feeling like they just strong armed me to sign the contract. Start date according contract that I signed will be only in two days.

Can I still change my mind? What would be the consequences of that for me? What do you think about hiring tactics of company B?

note: contract say that it is entered into with the condition of a three-month trial period. And I have been told that I can leave without any first signs. And I haven't even start a work there - my first day only in 2 days.

Comment: Well, what does your contract say about getting out of it?

Comment: Yeah, I am adult. But actually I don't know what my options are, so that why I am asked this question. I just like to know experienced people opinions on this situation.

Comment: Thanks teego1967. I think the same. YviDe, contract say that it is entered into with the condition of a three-month trial period. And I have been told that I can leave without any first signs. And I haven't even start a work there - my first day only in 2 days.

Comment: Personally I see nothing wrong, or at least *seriously* wrong with company B's tactics. You always had the option of not signing the contract if you did not approve of their "strong arming". They needed to sign up someone urgently so they tried pressuring you. It was a risky move, it paid off, but could have backfired too.

Comment: By the way, how would you like it if the company had "changed their mind" after you signed the contract?

Comment: "I will damage their company if I change my mind" sounds, to my ears, like a legal threat.

Comment: Masked Man, that's exactly - "they needed", but what about me, I needed a time to decide which offer to choose, and they didn't give me even a few days. It's not ethical too

Comment: @Jack I added your comment regarding the three month trial period because that is a key part of the situation and needed to be a part of the question.

Comment: @MaskedMan, company B's tactics actually are on the verge of backfiring on them if the OP recinds his acceptance. It does them no good to "strong-arm" somebody into signing exactly because of this situation. Filling a position can always wait a few days and that is something for candidates to keep in mind. There is little risk in delaying an acceptance for some fixed amount of time as long as one doesn't give the impression of stringing along an offer indefinitely.

Comment: @Jack Somehow, their "not ethical" tactics were fine with you until before you received the offer from company A? If you hadn't received the offer from company A, would you still call company B as "strong-arming" "not ethical", etc.? Don't go deciding what's "ethical" based on what is convenient to you in your given situation. Company B told you clearly to sign the offer by a given date, whether it was "right" or "wrong" is irrelevant. If you didn't approve of their tactics, you could have refused to sign or asked for more time before signing.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I still change my mind?

C**ertainly you can change your mind if you are willing to pay the consequences.** I don't know of any situation where a person is compelled by law to work for an employer.

> What would be the consequences of that for me?

That depends on the nature of the contract you signed, local laws, the willingness of Company B to pursue any remedies they may have available to them, etc.

You might be compelled by your signed contract to wait out a notice period. You should read and understand your contract (as you should have before signing it).

In almost any context, one consequence will be to your professional reputation. There will be at least a few folks who know of your going back on your word, and may hold it against you in the future.

> What do you think about hiring tactics of company B?

It's hard to know without seeing all the details.

You made the decision to take the "bird in hand" and sign the contract with company B rather than waiting for a decision from company A. And after seemingly changing your mind, you reaffirmed your choice and promised once again to work for them.

So it's hard to blame company B here for their admittedly "pretty good" offer. They might have pressured you a bit, but that's just business.

Their hiring tactics don't make any difference now anyway, unless they did something provably illegal. You have a choice to make. Other than feeling better about breaking the contract and going back on your word, even if folks agreed "company B is mean" it won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

When they said you need to decide now, that was their right to do so. You were hoping for more time to see if a better offer appeared. They were hoping to get a decision before they lost their second choice.

Now you need to review the terms of the contract you signed and see what is the procedure for cancelling it. Then abide by those terms. Keeping in mind that you should assume you are closing a door forever regarding that company.

Company B was taking risks by letting you have more time to decide. They could still lose you, they could lose money because a position would be unfilled. They might even have to start the search all over again. The risks they faced is why they gave you a deadline.